# Org mode - Copy cells from a remote org-table with shifted columns

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I want to copy the values of a shifted range of cells from a remote table.
Example:

```
#+NAME: TBL1
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
|   |   |   |   |

#+NAME: TBL2
|   | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
|   |   |   |   |   |
```

The table TBL1 should look like this in the end:

```
#+NAME: TBL1
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
```

I'm currently doing this with a dedicated function for each of 15+ cells, which makes the `#+TBLFM:` line super long and is not maintainable.
An efficient way to accomplish this is by using the lisp function `identity`:

```
#+NAME: TBL1
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
|   | 5 | 6 | 7 |
#+TBLFM: @2$1..@2$4='(identity remote(TBL2, @1$$#))
```

Problem is, that this function looks for values in the cells `@1$1..@1$4`. I want to shift the cells to look at to the right (`@1$2..@1$5`).
This has to be done via the REF value for the remote function, (`@1$$#`).
If I understand the syntax correctly, `$$#` is pointing to the current column of the cell which is going to be filled with the remote value (e.g. for cell `@2$1` in `TBL1`, `$$#` becomes `$1`). So this has to be shifted to the right with something like `$$#+1`.

What is the correct reference for my example?

Comment: Nice question!! Does replacing `@1$$#` with `(format "@1$%d" (+ 1 $#))` work? I’m away from emacs at moment so I can’t test syntax.

Comment: Thanks @Melioratus.
Evaluating the replacement leaves cells of `@2` of `TBL1` blank. No error notification.
I also checked `(format "@1$%d" 2)` which should format the string `@1$2` and result in  `| 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 |` for `@2` of `TBL1`, but `@2` stays also empty. Therefore using `format` might not work in general.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `org-table-get-remote-range` function with some string manipulation, although it's not pretty:

```
#+NAME: TBL1
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
#+TBLFM: @2='(org-table-get-remote-range "TBL2" (concat "@" "1$" (number-to-string (+ $# 1))))
```

Care must be taken to not write a reference literal in the lisp code to avoid immediate substitution of the table contents into the code before it is evaluated. For this reason the "@" is separate from the "1" in the `concat` function call.